# File and code structuring in DurandalJS

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, durandal

I'm trying to figure out a way to structure my app in a way that the API interactions are independent from my views and viewmodels.

At the moment, my ajax calls (get, add, save, remove, etc) and models (User model, Message model) are inside my view models, but in the future, we'll have a mobile app that will be a bit different from the desktop app, so I'd like to keep these actions accessible in one place.

I've seen people use a 'services' folder where they have models that handle loading and storing data, but haven't seen a complete structure that also includes handling new and current data.

Let's say I have a separate 'profile page' shell that includes a 'messages' tab and a 'user details' tab. This section needs the following:

- get user details
- get messages
- User Model
- Message Model
- add/edit/remove message
- edit user details

How would I go about structuring this? Individually by component (messages with model + get + add/edit/remove and user with model + get + edit in separate files/folders) or by site area (everything in one file/folder)?

Hopefully this makes sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not experienced in Durandal but have some positive background working with KO. I would recommend you to apply module pattern and incapsulate all your API service methods into the separate class (lets call it Router) also putting it into separate file. And then use methods of the Router class inside viewmodels.

```
// file with Router class

(function ($, ko, app) {
    app.Router = function () {
        var self = this;

        self.get = function (url, queryString, callBack) {
            $.get(url, data, function(data) {
                callBack(data);
            });
        };

        self.post = function (url, queryString, callBack) {
            $.post(url, data, function(data) {
                callBack(data);
            });
        };

    };
})(jQuery, ko, window.app)

// file with viewmodel

(function ($, ko, app) {
    app.UserModel = function () {
        var self = this;

        //create instance of Router class. 
        //Create it here just for the example. Will be better to create it out of the models to have just one instance. 
        //Or convert Router class to singleton
        var router = new app.Router();

        self.getUserDetails = function() {
            //use proper router method to GET data, providing params
            router.get(properRestServiceUrl, {userID: 1}, self.showUserDetails);
        };

        self.addMessage = function() {
            //use proper router method to POST data, providing params
            router.post(properRestServiceUrl, {userID: 1, message: 'test message'}, self.showConfirmation);
        };

        //callback function
        self.showUserDetails = function(data) {
            alert(data);
        };

        //callback function
        self.showConfirmation = function(data) {
            alert("The message was added successfully!");
        };

    };
})(jQuery, ko, window.app)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you use for back end, but in case it's ASP.NET MVC, I would strongly suggest checking out HotTowel template. Even if it's not ASP.NET MVC, it is still a good starting point to see how to efficiently structure your app.

http://www.asp.net/single-page-application/overview/templates/hottowel-template